# where is RabbitMQ internal API reference for plugin development

Tags: rabbitmq

I am developing a custom **RabbitMQ Plugin**, but I cannot find  anywhere the **internal API** reference (in erlang of course) that is solely internal to RabbitMQ. Is this documented somewhere ? Notice this is **not the erlang client API** that I am looking for, just the internal API reference for use from within RabbitMQ plugins.

As an example: I want to identify the listening port from within the plugling without to look at the config file. I assume the config file is loaded internally in RabbitMQ and is accessible from some internal API such as rabbitmq:getenv("port"), etc.. This is not specific to my problem, I simply need to know where the whole **internal** API reference is

Comment: so far, the only way I could find such details was form the source code of RabbitMQ Server...

Comment: you might have more luck if you ask this question on the RabbitMQ mailing list